# fstream variable get all lines in a text file

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to read all lines from a file, line by line with a `fstream` variable.

For example:

```
#include <fstream>

fstream fsFile;

fsfile.open("file.txt", ios::in);

while (fsFile.getline(szLine, LINE_SIZE + 1))
{
    cout << szLine << endl;
}
```

When I want to read all the lines but I got a line that is bigger than `LINE_SIZE` the `fsFile.bad()` returns true and I get it. 
But, I want to know how is it that `fsFile.getline(szLine, LINE_SIZE + 1)` suddenly returns `false`? 
I mean what is the return value of the function? 
If its `null` and I think it is why is it `null`? 
And when it is not `null` what it returns? 
Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `std::string` version of [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
std::ifstream fsFile("file.txt");
std::string line;
while(std::getline(fsFile, line)) {
    std::cout << line << '\n';
}
```

`getline` (both versions) returns a reference to the stream, which is convertible to `bool` so you can check it's state (if the read failed, typically because we hit the end of the file).

This version of `getline` is definitely preferable, because by using a `std::string` you completely stop worrying about the memory buffer. No need to create it yourself and remember to destroy it, no need to worry about the size of the line.

---

Also, please reconsider your use of what are often considered bad practices: [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191) and [`endl`](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html).